# How to restrict user input based on a row of values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

**I want to restrict the user input based on the values that I have stored in a specific row of a CSV file. But it always shows "Not Same" regardless of whether I  have inserted a value that exists in the CSV file.**

```
import pandas as pd

        import_file = pd.read_csv(r'EmployeeDetails\EmployeeDetails.csv')
        if  tkID.get() in import_file.iloc[:,0]:
            tkStatus.set("Enter valid User ID")
            status_label.update()
        else:
            tkStatus.set("Enter valid User Email")
            status_label.update()
```

Comment: Do you need test first column? Or first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is problem output from `tkID.get()` is string, so if need compare by integer column convert it to `int`, also for compare use mask with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) for test at least one match:

```
import_file = pd.read_csv(r'EmployeeDetails\EmployeeDetails.csv')
if  (import_file.iloc[:,0] == int(tkID.get())).any():
    tkStatus.set("Enter valid User ID")
    print('Exist in first column')
    status_label.update()
else:
    print('Not exist in first column')
    tkStatus.set("Enter valid User Email")
    status_label.update()
```

Comment: May I know how can i contact you?

Comment: @higgiewilliams - this is good way, comments. Some problem with solution?

Comment: Yes, it is ever prompting "Not exist in the first column" despite entering a value that is existed.

Comment: @higgiewilliams - are data in first column in file? If test `print (import_file.iloc[:,0].tolist())` there is looking value?

Comment: yes, it has. 
~~~
[1234, 12, 13, 123, 1]
Not exist in first column
~~~

Comment: So you test `1234` ?

Comment: @higgiewilliams - if it is number, try change `tkID.get()` to `int(tkID.get())`

Comment: yes, I have tested not only 1234 but other values too. 
```
1234  
[1234, 12, 13, 123, 1]
Not exist in first column
1  
[1234, 12, 13, 123, 1]
Not exist in first column
```

Comment: What is `print (type(import_file.iloc[0,0].tolist()))` and `print (type(tkID.get()))` if pass value?

Comment: " try change tkID.get() to int(tkID.get())" works !! Man, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
a = input("Enter your value")
if a in df.iloc[0, :]:
    print('Same')
else:
    print('Not Same')
```

Comment: I tried but it still not working as expected.

Comment: @higgiewilliams What is your goal?

Comment: If a user enters an ID that is existed in the CSV file, the status should prompt the user to " Enter a valid ID", else "Enter the other details".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try transforming your id-list into ndarray-type.

```
a = list("abcdefg")
b = np.arange(7)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":a, "B": b})

print(df)

"a" in df.iloc[:,0]

"a" in np.array(df.iloc[:,0])
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   a   0
1   b   1
2   c   2
3   d   3
4   e   4
5   f   5
6   g   6

False

True
```